# Problem with C++ Map

Tags: c++, algorithm, sorting, data-structures, dictionary

I am facing some problem with Map. I am developing an application where I am designing a database and I am facing a problem where I need to store table schema in Main Memory. The elements in the map are getting sorted automatically (as per the key) and I need the ordering to be as it is. I want the elements to be inserted in the Map as the way the user enters them. Is there an alternative data structure that I can use? Also, without knowing this fact, I have developed the entire application. Only during testing I could figure out this thing (My bad!). So, if I change to a completely different data structure, then there are several places in the code that needs modification. Please let me know if there is a simple way to eliminate this problem, or at least a similar data structure which I can use so that the operations on Map are similar to that of the new data structure.

This is the code I have written to achieve this:

```
class Attribute {
public:
    string attributeName;
    string type; //char, int, etc
    int size; //4 for int and corresponding size for char
};


class Table {
public:
    string tableName;
    map<string, Attribute> attribute;
    string primaryKey;
    int recordSize;
    int totalSize;
    int records;
};


Attribute CatalogMemoryHandler::createAttribute(string attributeName, string type, int size) {

    Attribute attribute;
    attribute.attributeName = attributeName;
    attribute.type = type;
    attribute.size = size;

    return attribute;
}


Table CatalogMemoryHandler::createTable(string tableName, string primaryKey, int recordsSize, int totalSize, int records) {

    Table tableObj;
    tableObj.tableName = tableName;
    tableObj.primaryKey = primaryKey;
    tableObj.recordSize = recordsSize;
    tableObj.totalSize = totalSize;
    tableObj.records = records;

    return tableObj;
}

bool CatalogMemoryHandler::addNewTable( string tableName,
                                            string primaryKey,
                            int recordSize,
                            int totalSize,
                            int records,
                            vector<string> listOfAttributeNames,
                            vector<string> listOfAttributeTypes,
                            vector<int> listofAttributeSizes
                ) {

Table newTable = createTable(tableName, primaryKey, recordSize, totalSize, records);

    for(int i = 0; i < (int) listOfAttributeNames.size(); i++) {

        Attribute attribute = createAttribute(listOfAttributeNames[i], listOfAttributeTypes[i], listofAttributeSizes[i]);
        newTable.attribute.insert( make_pair( listOfAttributeNames[i], attribute ) );
    }

        cout << "\n";
    table[tableName] = newTable;

    return true;
}
```

Please assist. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends on how you intend to use the data.  If you only occasionally need to access the data by key but generally just need to access it in the order in which it is inserted, you should just store the data in a `std::vector`:

```
std::vector<std::pair<Key, Value> > data;
```

As long as you always add elements using `push_back` and never reorder the elements (e.g. using `std::sort`), the elements will remain in the order in which you inserted them.  You can use the `std::find` to perform a linear search over the sequence to find the element with a given key.

If you need to frequently access elements by key but still need to maintain the order of insertion, you can use a `std::map` and a `std::vector` to contain the data:

```
std::map<Key, Value> data;
std::vector<Key> key_insertion_order;
```

Whenever you insert an element into `data`, add the key to the end of the `key_insertion_order` sequence.  Whenever you remove an element from `data`, remove the key from the sequence.

Comment: If elements are frequently added/removed then it will get slow to remove the key from vector especially if it is somewhere at the beginning as you need to move all the following keys to fill in the hole.

Comment: So, in order not to make modification to several places, I need to use a vector right? Also, how about HashMap? I believe it is unordered. I need to frequently access elements by key, so I need either a map or anything similar to it. Thanks for the reply though.

Comment: @stefanB:  It's not an ideal solution, but it's minimally invasive, which was one of the OP's requirements.

Comment: @Shankar:  `std::unordered_map` (and the non-standard `hash_map` provided by many implementations) does not store its elements in sorted order, but it also does not store its elements in insertion order.  Efficient access via key _and_ via insertion index can't be accomplished with a single Standard Library container:  you either need to use a pair of containers or you need to find a third-party container or write your own.

Comment: thanks for the reply. But, since I have done a lot of work already, I would like to follow Stefan's solution in maintaining a vector which contains key ordering. I will think of something better in version 2 of my application. Thanks a lot guys!

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can trick the map that, you add always the biggest elementh therefore map puts them at the end. But be carefull that this is not a safe code. Use it, if you make your insertions from a single point and single thread. here is the sample code

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <map>
#include <string>

class unordered
    : public std::binary_function<std::string,std::string,bool>
{
public:
    bool operator()(const std::string& lhs,const std::string& rhs)
    {
        if (lhs == str(NULL))
            return false;
        else
            return true;
    }

public:
    static const char* str(char* str_p)
    {
        static char* val_p = NULL;
        if (str_p != NULL)
            val_p = str_p;
        return val_p;           
    }

};

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    std::map<std::string,int,unordered> s_map;

    unordered::str("d");
    s_map.insert(std::make_pair("d",4));
    unordered::str("a");
    s_map.insert(std::make_pair("a",1));
    unordered::str("b");
    s_map.insert(std::make_pair("b",2));

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `unordered` is not a strict weak ordering; I don't think this would end well.